# How an event handler gets the state of a control that is created dynamically in the page_load

Tags: asp.net, controls

Based on certain conditions, I have created a few checkboxes, dropdownlists and textboxes dynamically in the page_load(). In the same page, I have a Submit button that is created during the design time (in the aspx page). Now in the click event handler of the Submit button, I need to get all the checkboxes that are checked and selected values from the dropdownlists, etc. But since those controls are created in the page_load, not during the design time, I couldn’t get any value. Is there any way I could get the values?

Update:

I have two more problems left:

drp.selectedIndex is always initialized to 0 not -1. I added drp.selectedIndex=-1 in the Page_Init. But in the cmdShow_Click, the drp.selectedIndex is 0.

Also,  the textbox's visibility is controlled by a checkbox. I have following code. But during postback, even the checkbox is checked, the textbox doesn’t show. Is there any way to fix it?

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
cb.ID = "cb" + id;
cb.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
cell.Controls.Add(cb);
cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.ID = "txt" + id;
tb.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
tb.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
cb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return cbOtherClicked('" + cb.ClientID + "', '" + tb.ClientID + "')");
cell.Controls.Add(tb);
cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));



    function cbOtherClicked(control1, control2) {
        var cbOther = document.getElementById(control1);
        var txtOther = document.getElementById(control2);

        if (cbOther.checked) {
            txtOther.style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
            txtOther.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Page_Init instead of Page_Load:

ASPX:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="cmdShow" runat="server" onclick="cmdShow_Click" Text="Show" /><br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Label>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
    chk.ID = "chk1";
    Panel1.Controls.Add(chk);
    DropDownList drp = new DropDownList();
    drp.ID = "drp1";
    drp.Items.Add(new ListItem("... Select ...",string.Empty));
    drp.Items.Add(new ListItem("ali","0"));
    drp.Items.Add(new ListItem("joseph", "1"));
    drp.Items.Add(new ListItem("mehdi", "2"));
    Panel1.Controls.Add(drp);
    TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
    txt1.ID = "txt1";
    Panel1.Controls.Add(txt1);
}
protected void cmdShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)Form.FindControl("chk1");
    DropDownList drp = (DropDownList)Form.FindControl("drp1");
    TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)Form.FindControl("txt1");
    string result = "";
    result += chk.Checked ? "CheckBox: Checked<br>" : "CheckBox: Unchecked<br>";
    result += drp.SelectedIndex!=-1 ? "DropDownList:"+drp.SelectedItem.Text+"<br>": "DropDownList: Not select<br>";
    result += string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt1.Text) ? "TextBox= Empty" : "TextBox= " + txt1.Text;
    Label1.Text = result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like charm. Save lots of headache for me.

Comment: Hey I have one more problem. Why the drp.selectedIndex is always initialized to 0 not -1. I added drp.selectedIndex=-1 in the Page_Init. But in the cmdShow_Click, the drp.selectedIndex is 0.

Comment: put to first item:drp.Items.Add(new ListItem("... Select ...",string.Empty));

Comment: I could do that. But do you know why the SelectedIndex is always initialized to 0?

Comment: Also, what about the textbox problem. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: in dropdownlist always in pageLoad or PageInit is first item selected. and -1 is not valid.